# React-Router-Dom 6 stop page refresh on useNavigate()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-persist

Hi I'm trying to use React-Router-Dom 6 with Redux Persist.

If I use

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
   navigate(`../../modules/${id});
```

It triggers a page refresh which triggers a rehydrate of the Persisted state.

Can I use useNavigate without reloading page?

Comment: Can you clarify what "triggers a page refresh" *actually* means? Is the browser window reloading? Or is something simply refetching some data? `useNavigate`, or rather `navigate`, alone doesn't reload the page/app.

Comment: The window appears to be reloading and a persist/REHYDRATE action is called.

Comment: I just added  { replace: false } to the options and that seems to have the desired effect. Is there a downside to not replacing?

Comment: Depends if you want a PUSH navigation or a REPLACE redirect to the path you are specifying. `replace` is false by default so I wonder if you had something else going on elsewhere in your code at that time.